# javascript regular expression replace 3digitis from path string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a `<img>` where I need to change two digits from the path. I have no idea in how to write regular expressions.

```
<img src="/cms/ig/immopix/100/9165c73366c8830058b0f95c0fcacef5_100.jpg" />
                          ^                                    ^ 
                          |                                    |
                           ------------------------------------
                                               |
                                   replace those "1" in "6" 

                                   so it looks like this
                            ------------------------------------
                           |                                    |
 <img src="/cms/ig/immopix/600/9165c73366c8830058b0f95c0fcacef5_600.jpg" />
```

The img name is an md5 value which could also contain "100", so I cannot just replace every "100". How can I do this?

So there are a few img tags in DOM which I loop like this

```
$('.object-overview-wrap').each(function(i){
    var img = $(this).children('.img-wrap').children('img');
    console.log(img.attr('src'));
    var imgSrc = img.attr('src');
    img.attr('src', '/cms/ig/immopix/600/88f9f658ed1d506ce36b28565b79405f_600.jpg');
        });
```

The console.log gives me: /cms/ig/immopix/100/9165c73366c8830058b0f95c0fcacef5_100.jpg which I would like to replace, but I don't know how.

Help and links explaining how to write and use regular expressions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could replace `"/100/"` with `"/600/"` and then `"_100."` with `"_600."`.

Regexes could of course work here, however it's simpler this way.

Comment: that's what I want to replace, but how?

Comment: Dunno. You haven't told us where this string is coming from.

Comment: `imgSrc.replace("/100/","/600/").replace("_100.","_600.")` should do it

Answer (score 2):

This should work for your case:

```
var s='<img src="/cms/ig/immopix/100/9165c73366c8830058b0f95c0fcacef5_100.jpg" />';
var r = s.replace(/100\b/g, "600");
//=> <img src="/cms/ig/immopix/600/9165c73366c8830058b0f95c0fcacef5_600.jpg" />
```

Or to make more strict:

```
var r = s.replace(/([/_])100\b/g, "$1600");
//=> <img src="/cms/ig/immopix/600/9165c73366c8830058b0f95c0fcacef5_600.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be: Avoid regex. Use maybe this:

```
var mystring = srcString.split('/');
mystring[4]=600;
mystring[5] = mystring[5].split('_')[0] + '_' + '600.jpg';
mystring.join('/');
```

Or similar.
Using `split` and `join` is fun. But a simple replace works here, too